# How can we convert numbers to 12 hour time format in Bigquery table

Tags: string, time, google-bigquery, integer, numbers

My bigquery table has a column which is of below format

23:00
19:00
15:00

and I want to convert them to time format(AM/PM)

11:00 PM
07:00 PM
03:00 PM

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [parse_time](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/time_functions#parse_time) and [format_time](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/time_functions#format_time):

```
select format_time('%I:%M %p', parse_time('%H:%M', '23:00'))
```

Try:

```
with mytable as (
  select '23:00' as column1 union all
  select '19:00' as column1 union all
  select '15:00' as column1
)
select format_time('%I:%M %p', parse_time('%H:%M', column1))
from mytable
```

[image]

Comment: But my data is of string type so do i need to cast it?

Comment: `parse_time` converts from `string` type to `time` type and then `format_time` converts from `time` type to `string` type

Comment: This is the error i get-- Mismatch between format character '1' and string character '2'

Comment: Added more examples